# ORA-06502 when comparing of Number datatype of ORA-06502 when querying AS400 table through ORACLE DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH

Tags: sql, oracle, db2-400

I'm trying to convert number format which is date "YYYYMMDD" to user specified date like "Last 7 days / 1 month data" using DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH from oracle database.

This query runs fine on AS400:

`SELECT * FROM AGNTPF 
WHERE 
START_DATE >= DEC(REPLACE(CHAR(CURRENT_DATE - 1 MONTH, ISO), '-', ''), 8, 0) )`

but when I run it from oracle using gateway

`declare
ret integer;
begin
ret := dbms_hs_passthrough.execute_immediate@P400(
'create TABLE AGNTPF1 AS
(SELECT * FROM AGNTPF WHERE START_DATE >= DEC(REPLACE(CHAR(CURRENT_DATE - 1 MONTH, ISO), '-', ''), 8, 0) ) with data');
end;
/
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 4`

Regards,

Gaurav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about db2400 / AS400, but to me, it looks like the SQL statement you pass to your procedure lacks proper escaping of the quotes. This should work:

```
declare
  ret integer;
begin
    ret := dbms_hs_passthrough.execute_immediate@P40(
            'create TABLE AGNTPF1 AS
            (SELECT * FROM AGNTPF WHERE START_DATE >= DEC(REPLACE(CHAR(CURRENT_DATE - 1 MONTH, ISO), ''-'', ''''), 8, 0) ) with data');
end;
```

Alternatively, you can use the famous `q` operator (here, I use the pipe symbol `|` to mark the beginning and end of the quoted string):

```
declare
  ret integer;
begin
    ret := dbms_hs_passthrough.execute_immediate@P40(
            q'|create TABLE AGNTPF1 AS
            (SELECT * FROM AGNTPF WHERE START_DATE >= DEC(REPLACE(CHAR(CURRENT_DATE - 1 MONTH, ISO), '-', ''), 8, 0) ) with data|');
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank, It worked. I didn't know about q operator. Please provide a link to study more about it.  Regards Gaurav

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617 and http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=311